# When I fire a XMP burster while moving, where is the center of the damage area?

Tags: ingress

When I fire a XMP Burster, during the animation I can move around the portal.
When the XMP will explode, which position will be used to compute the damages ?

Will it be the position where the fire began or the position where the fire stopped or something else (the middle of the move ?) ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The center is your location at the time the XMP burster is actually fired, which can vary highly depending on your internet connection.

It even happens that you are standing directly on top of a resonator, fire the XMP, but then due to some GPS glitch, you move away and the XMP is fired somewhere else.

In any way, you see the center and damage of your XMP on the screen.

**Edit:** I was looking for a credible source for my claim, but didn't find one. But I'm a very active Ingress player and there wasn't a single time XMPs behaved differently than I described above.

**Edit 2:**
Since yesterday (version 1.23.1), I've noticed a change in this behaviour. The visuals for firing the XMP now stay at the position the XMP was fired, even if you are moving away. So the correct answer now would be "The center is your location at the time you click on 'Fire'."

Comment: I've observed the same behaviour. I've had my GPS go haywire well firing an XMP and move me a street over. The centre of the blast was my "current" position (didn't his a single resonator).

Comment: Umm, your GPS position *can* vary highly, but that does *not* depend on your internet connection – only on the GPS satellites' visibility.

Comment: I can also vouch for this from personal experience - if you move after triggering the XMP, explosion is centered on where you are at time of firing.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs: Your position only depends on the GPS, but if your internet connection is bad, you can't really predict when your "Fire XMP" signal will reach the Ingress server and will be processed. So, your position is variable over time and your connection influences at what time it is fired.